# Missing notice on the Stack Exchange reputation graph

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stackexchange.com, reputation-graph

The [reputation points graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/974068/rekire?tab=reputation) only appears to show accounts with more than 200 reputation points. I've been wondering for a month why one of my accounts is missing in this graph. Now that one account has 215 reputation, but it is not visible. Is there another limit?

I think it would be helpful if the graph could have a notice explaining this. Could we have one?

Comment: Hm. There was a time that we hid sub-200 accounts from the "accounts" page under a fold that could be expanded. We've since made it so that all accounts are visible at all times, but I guess we never made any change on the graph so its limited scope is unstated. Nice catch.

Comment: @Grace yep, the tooltip can be changed to "Reputation across the network for accounts with at least 200 points" or something like that.

Comment: @GraceNote are there some updates? Is this issue on a todo list? :-)

Comment: No, no updates at the moment that I can offer.