# Possible search engine bug when searching for multiple tags (>2)

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I possible found a small bug in the search engine. I was looking for questions tagged with [c](/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). So I typed in *"[c] or [c++] or [c#]"*. On the right I get the following message:

> results found containing
>
> [c]
>
> tagged with [c](/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

But I don't entered the keywork *[c]* this should be only a tag. If I omit one of the tags every thing works as expected. By the way if I add *answers:0* at the beginning or at the end the keyword is detected correctly and not added as query.

Comment: Confirmed that's a bug, will take a look after getting the babby taken care of here.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help you. By the way I found [two more bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164491/171881). [This one here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160353/171881) is from the last year with no response in the last time.

Comment: The bug is perhaps even more apparent if you search for a bogus tag first, like `[reallybogus] or [c++] or [c#]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in a build rolling out now.  An *intended* optimization of `i = j;` in a loop (iterating the `or` statements in the parser) to avoid dupe processing bit me here.  It broke a later `terms[i] = "";` in the outer loop that was then at the wrong index, inadvertently leaving the first term.

Apologies for this being broken way longer than it should, it fell off my radar here.

Comment: Cool thank you for this fix. By the way what's about [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160353/171881). I think it should be quiet easy to fix.

Comment: @rekire I see 4 accounts in the graph, you have 4 accounts over 200 rep...am I missing something?

Comment: I mean the hint itself, that only accounts with more then 200 rep are displayed. AFIK this hint is only visible if the user has no accounts with more then 200 rep. Now I just see that 4 accounts without hints, some time ago I was wondering why only 3 where visible, it comes visible when I reached that limit but where should I guess that without hints? :-)